# INSERT INTO using SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am performing a INSERT INTO (with a select) basically coping the records to a staging tables using Data Manimpulation Languague (DML) and then this must cascade
to child tables.

The problem all the child table are inserting the identities from the parent tables into the staging tables which I want them to use the Identity Value of the staging tables
Tables are the same except for name and schema

The Code

```
DECLARE @FK_Value

INSERT INTO temp.tbl_staging_parent 
        (value1
        , value2)
SELECT        
        value1
       ,value2                
FROM         
    dbo.tbl_parent
WHERE 
    parent_id = @ParentID


SET @FK_Value = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

-- No Problems thus far
-- Here is the issue

INSERT INTO temp.tbl_staging_child  
        (FK
        , value2)
SELECT        
         value1
        ,value2               
FROM         
    dbo.tbl_child
WHERE 
    FK = @FK_Value
```

--- I did not include the Primary KEY and it is copying over the PK 
--- from the original tables when I need it to use the Identity of the staging tables

If anybody has some input please let me know.

Comment: I cannot post actual code it is to sensitive.  :(

Comment: Have a look at the [`OUTPUT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(v=sql.100).aspx) clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO temp.tbl_staging_child  
        (FK
        , value2)
SELECT        
         value1 -- this should be @FK_Value
        ,value2               
FROM         
    dbo.tbl_child
WHERE 
    FK = @FK_Value -- this should probably be FK = @ParentId
```

Comment: Why not take the identity and increment by 1 I am not setting that value.  The PK's on the child tables all have identity values... but again it is coping the data from the PRODUCTION tables to the STAGING tables when they need to be using IDENTITY VALUES

Comment: I don't know; based on my understanding of your question and slightly cryptic example, this is the solution.

The child tables' `FK` field references the parent tables' ID field, so you want to insert the staging parent ID (which is `@FK_Value` into the `staging_child` as the `FK` field, which this solution accomplishes.  Also, as you are selecting from the production `child` table, you want to select the production child record using the production parent ID, which is `@ParentId`.  Your existing example code uses @FK_Value, which is the staging parent ID identity value.

Comment: dbcc checkident ('tables', reseed, 0) 

Sorry all all the tables had to be reseeded.  When I created the staging tables they held on to the identity value.

Answer (score 0):

dbcc checkident ('tables', reseed, 0)

Sorry all all the tables had to be reseeded.  When I created the staging tables they held on to the identity value.